# Trouble Partitioning my Amazon Spectrum Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Getting this error in particular:

> ERROR: Error when calling external catalog API: The number of partition keys do not match the number of partition values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just posting this because googling that error turned nothing up. This can happen when you `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` on an external table created without the `PARTITIONED BY` clause.

Read this for details: [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html). In retrospect, you, like me, should have read this before trying this command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only specified **one partition field** in the `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` statement while in the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` I declared:

```
PARTITIONED BY (year varchar(4), month varchar(2), day varchar(2))
```

So the user is supposed to `ADD PARTITION` declaring the whole path, e.g.:

```
alter TABLE my_external_schema.my_external_table
add partition (year='2022', month='01', day='01') 
location 's3://my_bucket/year=2022/month=01/day=01/';
```